# SQL SELECT - group multiple values on a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with the following data:

```
ID  CAT  TYPE   SUBPRODUCT
--- ---- ------ ----------------
1   1     1       AA
2   1     1       BB
3   1     2       CC
```

I'd like to get the data like this:

```
CAT   TYPE   SUBPRODUCT
----- ------ ---------------
1     1      AA,BB
1     2      CC
```

pls reply me what should i do.

Thanks.

Comment: since it seems you got the help you needed, would you please accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `FOR XML PATH`. While a bit hard to read, afaik it currently is the most concise way to concatenate strings.

**Breakdown**

- `FOR XML PATH` concatenates all values that match the subselect
- `STUFF` removes the leading comma

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  q.CAT
        , q.TYPE
        , SUBPRODUCT = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + qi.SUBPRODUCT FROM q qi WHERE qi.Cat = q.Cat AND qi.Type = q.Type FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM    q
GROUP BY
        q.CAT
        , q.TYPE
```

**Test script**

```
;WITH q AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
    (1, 1, 1, 'AA')
    , (2, 1, 1, 'BB')
    , (3, 1, 2, 'CC')
  ) AS a (ID, CAT, TYPE, SUBPRODUCT)    
)
SELECT  q.CAT
        , q.TYPE
        , SUBPRODUCT = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + qi.SUBPRODUCT FROM q qi WHERE qi.Cat = q.Cat AND qi.Type = q.Type FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM    q
GROUP BY
        q.CAT
        , q.TYPE
```